# What are the efficient ways of reading a physics research paper, understand and come up with new ideas?

Tags: soft-question, research-level

I am planning to do research in theoretical particle physics and phenomenology. But as opposed to reading a textbook, I find that understanding journal papers to complete satisfaction could be quite challenging. This includes working out all the mathematical details, conceptual issues, understanding figures etc. I believe here are many experienced researchers out here who can help me in this regard and share their experiences. What are the effective and economical ways to read and understand a research paper? Also, how do people come up with new ideas by reading others' work?

Comment: I dunno of any efficient way.  Some papers can take months to read.

Comment: No I mean just reading some of these papers in some depth can take months.

Comment: This is a prime example of *primarily opinion based* question that is considered *off topic* explicitly in [help].

Comment: My opinion is that if you haven’t mastered the basic material covered in pedagogical textbooks, you’ll have little success in understanding research papers. They are often an order of magnitude more difficult to understand. A research paper is to a graduate textbook what a graduate textbook is to a high-school textbook.

Comment: My other opinion is that if you want to do serious research that has a chance of being taken seriously, rather than having physics as a hobby, you must get a Ph.D. You can’t get a Ph.D. without reading textbooks.

Comment: *I believe here are many experienced researchers out here who can help me in this regard and share their experiences.* Be realistic. They’re busy people. They might give you a few minutes of their time. They’re not going to hand-hold you through a research paper, especially if you don’t already know the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my process:
First, I read the abstract and the conclusion/discussion part. From there I know whether the paper really is what I am looking for or not. While doing this, I make sure to highlight/underline whatever seems most relevant. I'll then start properly reading the paper, keeping in mind the key things I read from the first scan. In this step I usually like to work out any missing steps in the paper (just to keep myself on my toes - some papers can get boring).

Remember that papers (especially at the forefront of research) are written by researchers (humans), so make sure that you are critical of everything you read. Just because it's in a paper doesn't make it automatically right. A good paper often tells a compelling story, in a sense. Make sure that the story makes sense to you and always be on the lookout for typos (they happen way more than they should, even in good journals).

As for your last question, there really isn't a good answer. If you're just starting out, focus on getting acquainted with the material and deeply understanding what the problems in your field are. At some point you may have an idea of how you want to extend someone else's work in a direction they haven't gone in.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This is quite useful.